# Access multidimensional array elements with a pointer in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, multidimensional-array, dereference

I'm trying to access the elements of a multidimensional array with a pointer in C++:

```
#include<iostream>

int main() {

  int ia[3][4] = {
    {0, 1, 2, 3},
    {4, 5, 6, 7},
    {8, 9, 10, 11}
  };

  int (*pia)[4] = &ia[1];
  std::cout << *pia[0] 
    << *pia[1]
    << *pia[2]
    << *pia[3]
    << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

I'm expecting `*pia` to be the second array in `ia` and therefore the output to be 4567.

However the output is 4814197056, so I'm obviously doing it wrong. How do I the access the elements in the rows correctly?

Comment: Try this `int * pia = ia[1];`

Comment: No warnings with ´-std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic´. @i486: ´error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘int’)
             std::cout << *pia[0]´

Comment: ... `std::cout << pia[0];`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it stands, you would have to write

```
std::cout << (*pia)[0] ...
```

because `[]` binds more strongly than `*`. However, I think what you really want to do is

```
int *pia = ia[1];
std::cout << pia[0] 
          << pia[1]
          << pia[2]
          << pia[3]
          << std::endl;
```

Addendum: The reason you get the output you do, by the way, is that `*pia[i]` is another way of writing `pia[i][0]`. Since `pia[0]` is `ia[1]`, `pia[1]` is `ia[2]`, and `pia[2]` and beyond are garbage (because `ia` is too short for that), you print `ia[1][0]`, `ia[2][0]` and then garbage twice.

Comment: For reference: [C++ Operator Precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't aware that the index operator can be used on pointers that way. So in the original code (with `(*pia)[i]`) I used a mixture of a pointer to `int[]` and array indexing whereas your suggestion relies on pointers alone (and row-major order). Are there any advantages in using "plain" pointer arithmetic here or is it a matter of style?

Comment: It looks clearer and more common. And anyway it *is* exactly the same as array indexing. This is because arrays decay into pointers at the drop of a hat; whenever you write `arr[i]`, the array decays into a pointer on which pointer arithmetic then proceeds to happen.

Answer (score 1):

I used the below way to print, It works well.

```
std::cout << (*pia)[0]
         << (*pia)[1]
         << (*pia)[2]
         << (*pia)[3] 
         << std::endl;
```

In precedence table of C++, [] has higher priority than *.

Answer (score 0):

```
  int *pia[] = { &ia[1][0], &ia[1][1], &ia[1][2], &ia[1][3] };
```

or

```
    int* pia = static_cast<int*>(&ia[1][0]);
  std::cout << pia[0] << " "
    << pia[1] << " "
    << pia[2] << " "
    << pia[3] << " "
    << std::endl;
```